# How to execute a block function in home page?

Tags: magento2, template, static-block, home, home-page

This is My Layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Vendor\Namespace\Block\Index\Custom" template="Vendor_Namespace::cms.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This is My block file:

```
 <?php
    namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Index;

    class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        public function Newly(){
       return "hello";
    }
    }
```

Phtml File

```
<?php echo Newly();
?>
```

But no changes in home page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do your task like this:

Open your cms page from **Admin->Content->Home Page**

Now call your **phtml with custom block** in cms page

```
{{block class="Vendor\Namespace\Block\Index\Custom" template="Vendor_Namespace::cms.phtml"}}
```

> Vendor\Namespace\Block\Index\Custom.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Block\Index;

class Custom extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    public function Newly()
    {
       return "hello";
    }
}
```

> Vendor\Namespace\view\frontend\templates\cms.phtml

```
<?php echo Newly(); ?>
```

Flush cache by `php bin/magento cache:flush`